# formatting groups of cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe is shown below

```
import pandas as pd

inp_df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt",   "auc",  82.5,  80.1,  83.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt", "pr@5%",   0.3,   0.2,   0.4],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt", "re@5%",  60.2,  58.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn",   "auc",  84.1,  83.8,  84.5],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn", "pr@5%",   0.5,   0.4,   0.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn", "re@5%",  61.5,  61.4,  61.7],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm",   "auc",  84.3,  84.1,  84.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm", "pr@5%",   0.8,   0.7,   0.9],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm", "re@5%",  61.2,  61.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt",   "auc",  82.5,  80.1,  83.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt", "pr@5%",   0.3,   0.2,   0.4],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt", "re@5%",  60.2,  58.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm",   "auc",  84.3,  84.1,  84.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm", "pr@5%",   0.8,   0.7,   0.9],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm", "re@5%",  61.2,  61.1,  61.3],
  ], columns=["A","B","C","model","metric","val","val_lo","val_hi"])
```

I would like to display it as shown below [image: output]

Notes:

1. for each `metric` (eg `auc`) use **bold** for model with highest `val`
2. highlight cells for all models (within that (A,B,C)) with overlapping (val_lo,val_hi) which are the confidence intervals.
3. draw a line after each set of models

---

I came up with a solution which takes me most of the way

```
cols = ["val","val_lo","val_hi"]
inp_df["value"] = list(inp_df[cols].to_records(index=False))
inp_df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)

out_df = inp_df.pivot(index=inp_df.columns[:4], columns="metric", values="value")\
              .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
out_df
```

```
    A   B   C model                 auc            pr@5%               re@5%
0  a1  b1  c1   gbt  [82.5, 80.1, 83.6]  [0.3, 0.2, 0.4]  [60.2, 58.1, 61.3]
1  a1  b1  c1   llm  [84.3, 84.1, 84.6]  [0.8, 0.7, 0.9]  [61.2, 61.1, 61.3]
2  a1  b1  c1   rnn  [84.1, 83.8, 84.5]  [0.5, 0.4, 0.6]  [61.5, 61.4, 61.7]
3  a1  b1  c2   gbt  [82.5, 80.1, 83.6]  [0.3, 0.2, 0.4]  [60.2, 58.1, 61.3]
4  a1  b1  c2   llm  [84.3, 84.1, 84.6]  [0.8, 0.7, 0.9]  [61.2, 61.1, 61.3]
```

```
mets = ["auc","pr@5%","re@5%"]
def flag(block):
  out = [block["model"].values.tolist()]
  for met in mets:
    val,lo,hi = map(np.array, zip(*block[met].values))
    maxind = val.argmax()
    overlapbool = np.logical_and(hi[maxind]>=lo, lo[maxind]<=hi)
    overlapinds = set(np.where(overlapbool)[0]) if overlapbool.sum()>1 else set()
    
    curr = list()
    for n,(x,y,z) in enumerate(zip(val,lo,hi)):
      cell = f"{x:.1f} ({y:.1f}-{z:.1f})"
      if n==maxind: cell += "*"
      if n in overlapinds: cell += "†"
      curr.append(cell)
    out.append(curr)
  return pd.DataFrame(zip(*out), columns=["model"]+mets)

out_df.groupby(["A","B","C"]).apply(flag).droplevel(-1).set_index(["model"], append=True)\
  .style.applymap(lambda val:"font-weight:bold" if "*" in val else None)\
    .applymap(lambda val:f"background-color:beige" if "†" in val else None)
```

[image]

I hope to be able to resolve the following

1. have the models in the order [gbt, rnn, llm].  Right now even if I made that row an ordered Categorical, that does not seem to work.
2. draw a line after each set of models.  So, in this figure there would be one line between block (a1,b1,c1) and (a1,b1,c2).
3. drop characters * and † which I am introducing for cell level formatting but would be great to get rid of.

Comment: Observation : you can't draw a line in pandas so your question still have to show some informations about your environment

Comment: If you use Excel and want bold and a line, I suppose you must use some VBA code. For instance, every time VBA encounters the symbol `*` , it erases this symbol and print the text in bold.

Answer (score 0):

To follow and understand script steps, just `print` **r** or **r2** or **r3** or **r4** :

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt",   "auc",  82.5,  80.1,  83.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt", "pr@5%",   0.3,   0.2,   0.4],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "gbt", "re@5%",  60.2,  58.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn",   "auc",  84.1,  83.8,  84.5],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn", "pr@5%",   0.5,   0.4,   0.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "rnn", "re@5%",  61.5,  61.4,  61.7],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm",   "auc",  84.3,  84.1,  84.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm", "pr@5%",   0.8,   0.7,   0.9],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1", "llm", "re@5%",  61.2,  61.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt",   "auc",  82.5,  80.1,  83.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt", "pr@5%",   0.3,   0.2,   0.4],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "gbt", "re@5%",  60.2,  58.1,  61.3],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm",   "auc",  84.3,  84.1,  84.6],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm", "pr@5%",   0.8,   0.7,   0.9],
    ["a1", "b1", "c2", "llm", "re@5%",  61.2,  61.1,  61.3],
  ], columns=["A","B","C","model","metric","val","val_lo","val_hi"])

r = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C','model',"metric"], \
            value_vars=["val","val_lo","val_hi"])

def func(g):
    val = g.iloc[0, 6]
    val_lo = g.iloc[1, 6]
    val_hi = g.iloc[2, 6] 
    g['val'] = "%s(%s-%s)"%(val, val_lo, val_hi)
    return(g)

r2 = (r.groupby(['A','B','C','model', 'metric'])
       .apply(lambda g: func(g))
       ).drop(labels=['variable', 'value'], axis=1)

r3 =( (r2.groupby(['A','B','C','model'])
        .apply(lambda g: g.pivot(columns="metric", values='val').bfill().ffill())
        .reset_index(2)
        )
      .drop_duplicates()
      .droplevel(3)
      .reset_index()
      )

extract=lambda s: float( s.split('(')[0] )
def gmax(g):
    cols = ['auc', 'pr@5%', 're@5%']
    g2 = g[cols].applymap(extract)
    for col in cols:
        g.loc[g2[col].idxmax(),col] = '*%s*'%(g.loc[g2[col].idxmax(),col],)
    return g
    
r4 = ( r3.groupby(['A', 'B' ,'C'])
         .apply(lambda g: gmax(g))
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       ).sort_values(by='C')

r4.columns.name=''

print(r4)
```

**Result**

Bold is indicated with punctuation `*` in `gmax` function (`**` in markdown)

```py
    A   B model   C                auc           pr@5%              re@5%
0  a1  b1   gbt  c1    82.5(80.1-83.6)    0.3(0.2-0.4)    60.2(58.1-61.3)
1  a1  b1   llm  c1  *84.3(84.1-84.6)*  *0.8(0.7-0.9)*    61.2(61.1-61.3)
2  a1  b1   rnn  c1    84.1(83.8-84.5)    0.5(0.4-0.6)  *61.5(61.4-61.7)*
3  a1  b1   gbt  c2    82.5(80.1-83.6)    0.3(0.2-0.4)    60.2(58.1-61.3)
4  a1  b1   llm  c2  *84.3(84.1-84.6)*  *0.8(0.7-0.9)*  *61.2(61.1-61.3)*
```

**Bonus**

A trick to order into the required presentation

```py
ds = {0:0, 1:2, 2:1, 3:3, 4:4}
order = list(map(lambda m: ds[m], r4['model'].index))
r4 = r4.sort_values(by='model', ignore_index=True, key = lambda o:order)
```

```py
    A   B model   C                auc           pr@5%              re@5%
0  a1  b1   gbt  c1    82.5(80.1-83.6)    0.3(0.2-0.4)    60.2(58.1-61.3)
1  a1  b1   rnn  c1    84.1(83.8-84.5)    0.5(0.4-0.6)  *61.5(61.4-61.7)*
2  a1  b1   llm  c1  *84.3(84.1-84.6)*  *0.8(0.7-0.9)*    61.2(61.1-61.3)
3  a1  b1   gbt  c2    82.5(80.1-83.6)    0.3(0.2-0.4)    60.2(58.1-61.3)
4  a1  b1   llm  c2  *84.3(84.1-84.6)*  *0.8(0.7-0.9)*  *61.2(61.1-61.3)*
```

Comment: I process at that point but I don't clearly understand the criterium to choose row inside each group, `max or min of auc / pr@5% / re@5%` ?

Comment: `max` for each column separately (auc, pr@5%, re@5%)

Comment: But the max of each column inside a group could be on different rows, how do you handle that ?

Comment: please see the example image in my question - it is the max across models.  Given (a1,b1,c1) which model did the best.  I am not sure after compressing the way you have, that step would be easy.

Comment: ok I understand finally I am working on it

Comment: Sorting is in the following `ascending` order : `auc` thus `pr@5%` thus `re@5%` and then keep the last row for each group

Comment: Hello Laurent. Would you please explain `g['val'] = "%s(%s-%s)"%(val, val_lo, val_hi)`? I am afraid I am not familiar with the application of `"%s(%s-%s)"%(val, val_lo, val_hi)`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello @AnoushiravanR : `"%s(%s-%s)"%(val, val_lo, val_hi)"` is equivalent to `"...".format(...)` and `g['val'] = value` gives the value to all column

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It sounds interesting to know.